# Histogram in python from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, histogram

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'user':user1, 'yob':1984, 'saves':24, 'hidden':28},
{'user':user2, 'yob':1989, 'saves':7, 'hidden':51}, {...}, ...]
```

And I want to make a stacked histogram plot of saves and hidden on the y-axis and yob on the x-axis. So the histogram should bin by **yob** and sum the number of saves or hidden for each dictionary in the list. For example, if there are 3 dictionaries with the common yob 1998 with saves of 8, 19 and 4 then the total saves for yob 1998 should be 31 and the hist plot for saves should be 31 in height in 1998. So something like:

```
plt.hist([list_of_dicts['yob']['saves'], list_of_dicts['yob']['hidden']],
bins=45, stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Not sure on the syntax to do this or how to access the elements in the list correctly, could anyone help? Thanks
*Edit: I know you can't index a list using a string (list_of_dicts['yob']) but that is where I am stuck and asking the question.

Answer (score 3):

you can first put everything in a single dictionary,

```
master_dict = {}
# initialize the arrays first
for key in list_of_dicts[0]:
    master_dict[key] = [d[key] for d in list_of_dicts]
```

Then, use `pandas` to bin by `'yob'`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(master_dict)
bins = numpy.linspace(df.yob.min(), df.yob.max(), 45)
cut = pd.cut(df.yob, bins)
group = df.groupby(cut)
```

The following lines give you the sum of each of the other dictionary items binned by `yob`:

```
nsaves = group.saves.sum()
nhidden = group.hidden.sum()
```

which you can then plot with the bins defined above using `plt.step` or `plt.bar`:

```
plt.step(bins[:-1], nsaves, color='r', where='pre')
plt.step(bins[:-1], nhidden, color='b', where='pre')
```